# Python pandas timeseries, empty space under header

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am importing a timeseries from a csv file, when I do there appears a 0-index above my time stamps, I don't seem to get rid of it.

Code

```
df = pd.read_csv((FileLocation), header=None, index_col=0)
```

Result:

```
                              1
0                              
2013-12-29 17:49:00+00:00  7080
2013-12-29 17:50:00+00:00  7080
2013-12-29 17:51:00+00:00  7020
2013-12-29 17:52:00+00:00  8520
2013-12-29 17:53:00+00:00  7020
2013-12-29 17:54:00+00:00  6960
2013-12-29 17:55:00+00:00  7020
2013-12-29 17:56:00+00:00  6900
2013-12-29 17:57:00+00:00  4200
```

Does anyone have a suggestion of what I should try?

Comment: What does your file look like? Is there an empty line? Try `skiprows=1`.

Comment: What is your recommended output?

Comment: And welcome to Stackoverflow. More info about [site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the index name to `None`.

```
df.index.name = None
```

Confirmation of result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [1, 2, 3]}, index=pd.Index([0, 1, 2], name=0))

>>> df
   1
0   
0  1
1  2
2  3

df.index.name = None

>>> df
   1
0  1
1  2
2  3
```